# Spring @Autowired not work in @Endpoint

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I want to create some Web service through Spring framework, but I found something wrong, `@Autowired`  not work in `@Endpoint`. Please see my code:

```
    @Endpoint
    public class VideoEndpoint
    {
        private VideoService videoService;
        @Autowired
        public VideoEndpoint(VideoService videoService)
        {
            this.videoService=videoService;
        }

        @PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://www.skysoft.top/ws/video", localPart = "GetVideoRequest")
        @ResponsePayload
        public GetVideoResponse findVideoById(@RequestPayload GetVideoRequest request)
                throws Exception
        {
            GetVideoResponse response = new GetVideoResponse();
            Video video=videoService.getVideoByAid(request.getAid());
            response.setVideo(video);
            return response;
        }
    }


    public interface VideoService {

        List<Video> getVideoList();
        Video getVideoByAid(long aid);
    }


    @Service("videoService")
    @Transactional
    public class VideoServiceImpl implements VideoService {
        private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
        @Autowired
        private VideoDao videoDao;
        @Autowired
        private RedisCache cache;


        @Override
        public List<Video> getVideoList() {
            String cache_key=RedisCache.CAHCENAME+"|getVideoList";
            //先去缓存中取
            List<Video> result_cache=cache.getListCache(cache_key, Video.class);
            if(result_cache==null){
                //缓存中没有再去数据库取，并插入缓存（缓存时间为60秒）
                result_cache=videoDao.queryAll();
                cache.putListCacheWithExpireTime(cache_key, result_cache, RedisCache.CAHCETIME);
                LOG.info("put cache with key:"+cache_key);
            }else{
                LOG.info("get cache with key:"+cache_key);
            }
            return result_cache;
        }
    @Override
        public Video getVideoByAid(long aid) {
            return videoDao.queryByAid(aid);
        }


    }
    This is my Spring-ws-servelet.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd">
        <context:annotation-config/>
        <!-- 自动扫描@Endpoint注解 -->
        <!--<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter" />-->
        <!--<context:component-scan base-package="com.yingjun.ssm.service" />-->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.yingjun.ssm.ws.endpoint" />
        <!-- 开启Spring WebService的注解自动扫描驱动 -->
        <sws:annotation-driven/>
        <!-- 动态WSDL的配置 -->
        <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="video" portTypeName="VideoOperation" locationUri="/webservice/video"
                          targetNamespace="http://www.skysoft.top/ws/video">
            <sws:xsd location="classpath:wsdl/video.xsd" />
        </sws:dynamic-wsdl>


    </beans>

This is my web.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <!--配置DispatcherServlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- 配置SpringMVC需要加载的配置文件 spring-xxx.xml -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-*.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <!--默认匹配所有的请求 -->
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- druid -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DruidStatView</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.alibaba.druid.support.http.StatViewServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DruidStatView</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/druid/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>DruidWebStatFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.alibaba.druid.support.http.WebStatFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>exclusions</param-name>
            <param-value>*.js,*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.css,*.ico,/druid/*</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>DruidWebStatFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/spring-ws-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

 This is my spring-service.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <!-- 自动扫描@Endpoint注解 -->
    <!--<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter" />-->
    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="com.yingjun.ssm.service" />-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yingjun.ssm.ws.endpoint" />
    <!-- 开启Spring WebService的注解自动扫描驱动 -->
    <sws:annotation-driven/>
    <!-- 动态WSDL的配置 -->
    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="video" portTypeName="VideoOperation" locationUri="/webservice/video"
                      targetNamespace="http://www.skysoft.top/ws/video">
        <sws:xsd location="classpath:wsdl/video.xsd" />
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>


</beans>
```

I request the Web service through SoapUI, but it always go wrong:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'videoEndpoint' defined in file [C:\Users\PAN\IdeaProjects\beauty_ssm\target\beauty_ssm_0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_20170603\WEB-INF\classes\com\yingjun\ssm\ws\endpoint\VideoEndpoint.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.yingjun.ssm.service.VideoService]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.yingjun.ssm.service.VideoService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.yingjun.ssm.service.VideoService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.yingjun.ssm.service.VideoService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
20:38:34.634 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@552e7868: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,videoEndpoint,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.mapping.SoapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.DomPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SourcePayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.JaxbElementPayloadMethodProcessor#0,org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SimpleSoapExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema#0,video,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
20:38:34.635 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR o.s.w.t.h.MessageDispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'videoEndpoint' defined in file [C:\Users\PAN\IdeaProjects\beauty_ssm\target\beauty_ssm_0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_20170603\WEB-INF\classes\com\yingjun\ssm\ws\endpoint\VideoEndpoint.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.yingjun.ssm.service.VideoService]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.yingjun.ssm.service.VideoService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.yingjun.ssm.service.VideoService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.yingjun.ssm.service.VideoService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

I have found many solutions, but not working.

Comment: I assume all these classes have the package of "com.yingjun.ssm.ws.endpoint"? It seems VideoServiceImpl class is not registered?

Comment: Thank you. there are many configure files in my project, such as spring-service.xml, this file will register the service class VideoServiceImpl . But it seems the spring-service.xml registered classes cannot find by the @Endpoint, very strange.

Comment: post your web.xml

Comment: Its not the endpoint it complains about. Its not finding the com.yingjun.ssm.service.VideoService interface. Perhaps annotate this interface too.

Comment: @David Florez Thank you. I have posted the web.xml.

Comment: @MinhKieu Thank you. Do you mean annotate this interface VideoService too? What annotation should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert but i think that your end point class is not aware of your applicationContext. put this at the top of your `web.xml`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Every *-servlet.xml file that you define will have a different context, the ‘contextLoaderListener‘ will create a parent context so you can share Beans between contexts.

if that does not work try adding this to your Spring-ws-servelet.xml inside the `<beans>` tag

```
<import resource="spring-service.xml"/>
```

Comment: This is wiring via XML which is what @annotion used as alternative. If you look at the stacktrace, it said `No qualifying bean of type [com.yingjun.ssm.service.VideoService]`. Autowired is looking for type matching. I strongly think @annocation the interface will work.

Comment: @David Florez Thank you. But there is not a applicationContext.xml in my project, <context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yingjun.ssm.service" /> in my spring-service.xml.

Comment: @孙盼盼 I modified my answer with the new info

Comment: @David Florez That's perfect! It solved my problem! Thank you so much!

Comment: @David Florez Done. Thank you.